# Correct Way to Test Just the Interaction Term with Multiple Regression

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-regression, interaction

Multiple regression will be performed on the following, to determine if the **interaction term** is significant:
1.The dependent variable A is continuous;
2.There are two independent variables, X and Y, which are Boolean.

I used lm() in R, isolating for just the interaction term.

```
lm(A ~ X:Y, data = SomeData)

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
                  Estimate    Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         252.04    6.42e-06 ***
XTrue:YFalse        126.57    0.0623 .  
XFalse:YFalse       156.61    0.0212 *  
XTrue:YTrue          59.32    0.3594    
XFalse:YTrue          NA         NA      

F-statistic p-value: 0.08724
```

How do I interpret this, when testing whether the interaction between X and Y is significant, at the 0.05 confidence level?  Is this the correct way to run this?

I avoided using `lm(A ~ X*Y, data = SomeData)` to isolate for X:Y. Is that necessary? I have read that using step-wise regression to remove terms can affect the p-values.

The Likelihood Ratio Test returns `Pr(>Chisq) = .2804`

```
a <- lm(A ~ X+Y, data=SomeData)
b <- lm(A ~ X*Y, data=SomeData)
lmtest::lrtest(a, b)
```

Running the full model returns an intercept + 3 term model, with a single interaction term, `XFalse:YTrue, p = 0.317`

```
lm(A~X*Y, data=SomeData)
```

Which one is correct?  Can I do this just using multiple regression, without using the Likelihood Ratio Test? I am worried that running multiple tests affects the p-value - is that true?

Comment: I think you can use likelihood ratio test. `lmtest::lrtest()` can test `lm(A~X*Y)` and `lm(A~X+Y)`.

Comment: Your intercept already captures the case of $X=0$ & $Y=0$, so it should not be included. In general, interaction terms between dichotomous variables aren't a good idea.

Comment: @Durden Why not? The interaction effect between smoking status and sex on disease is common in epi researchers.

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more precise: I meant interaction terms of dichotomous variables in the way Larry implemented it. After all, he's just comparing different means. His regression model should be $A = \mu + \mathbf{1}(X=1) + \mathbf{1}(Y=1) + \mathbf{1}(X=1,Y=1)$, where $\mathbf{1}$ is the indicator function.

Comment: @Durden  - I don't know how to leave out the intercept.  If I add either + 0 or -1 to the call, all the significance values get crazy low.  Those NA's also get replaced with real numbers.

Comment: @Larry I think your goal is to test for the interaction effect between `XY`. Why do you care about intercepts? You only need to see if the p value from `lmtest::lrtest(model0, model1)`, where `model0 = lm(A~X+Y)` and `model0 = lm(A~X*Y)`.

Comment: Durden said to leave out the intercept.  I tagged the wrong person in my comment - fixed.

Comment: @Larry, I meant the case $X=0, Y=0$ should not be included. The intercept needs to remain.

Comment: @Durden. Agreed. Intercept remains and test for $\mathbb{1}(X=1,Y=1)$.

Comment: @WCMC - Is there a way to do this just doing multiple regression?

Comment: Significant in what regression equation? I think you want the one with the interaction, each term individually, and an intercept.

Comment: Likelihood Ratio Test returns Pr(>Chisq) = .2804

Comment: @Durden - I don't understand your notation.  What is "1(x=1,y=1)" in terms of lm(A ...) ?

Comment: $\mathbf{1}(X=1,Y=1)$ is a dummy variable taking on the value 1 whenever both X and Y are true, and 0 otherwise.

Comment: @Durden I'll have to research how to do that in R. I'm wondering why this is so complicated, when ANOVA is supposed to give the same results as linear regression, and it's so easy to do this with ANOVA.

Comment: I'll give you a hint: if $X$ is either zero or one, and $Y$ is either zero or one, then $X\cdot Y$ is equal to 1 only if $X$ and $Y$ are both equal to one, and zero otherwise.

Comment: I understand a logical AND statement...  I'm Googling as whatever you are saying isn't clicking.

Comment: @Durden My attempt to get someone to implement your answer in R at stackoverflow was CLOSED.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63478058/r-how-to-force-a-specific-interaction-term-in-regression

Comment: @Durden what’s the problem with being zero if either $X=0$ or $Y=0?$

Comment: @Dave - I think Durden is just saying to use the full model, A*B, and then look at the p-value for the interaction term, and he is just being very cryptic about it.  In a comment he made above, A=μ+1(X=1)+1(Y=1)+1(X=1,Y=1), seems to match the full model, X + Y + XY.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple websites say that the correct p-value for the significance of the interaction is given using the standard

```
lm(A ~ X*Y, data=SomeData)
```

which returns

```
                    Estimate  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         376.79     4.7e-09 ***
XFalse               32.03     0.631    
YTrue               -67.21     0.312    
XFalse:YTrue        -90.38     0.317
```

So the p-value to use in the given hypothesis test is 0.317. (H: Is the interaction significant? Not at p < 0.05.)

If you think this is not correct, then please post the correct answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Please don't post a tentative answer & ask for comments / corrections. That isn't how SE sites work. If you want to do that, post your attempted solution as part of your question statement.

Comment: FWIW, this is correct.  `XFalse:YTrue` is the test of the interaction. Your p-value is `.317`.  Scientific culture requires the use of .05 as alpha; from a purely logical point of view, you can use whatever alpha you like, but setting $\alpha\ge.32$ would be pretty strange. The interaction isn't significant.

Comment: Thanks.  (If you are referring to my answer, "Is the interaction significant" is quoting the hypothesis." I'm updating to clarify. )